# Trying to make a responsive nav hide the options by default in each page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

I made a responsive nav that hides all of the pages for mobile view. It is toggled and appears when the user clicks the menu nav. The thing is when you go to another page then the nav stays open. I want the nav to stay closed when visiting any page.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mw59vvcm/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Taffies Cupakes</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/header.png" alt="taffies logo"></a>
    </header> <!-- end of header -->

<aside class="sidebar">
    <nav>
        <div class="menu"></div>
        <ul class="main_nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">about us</a></li>
            <li><a href="orders.html">orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> <!-- end of nav -->

        <div class="company_info">
            <p>Taffies cupcakes</p>
            <p>111 x drive road</p>
            <p>milton keynes</p>
            <p>l0002</p><br>
            <p>telephone: 078 878-8888</p>
        </div> <!-- end of compnay info text -->

</aside> <!-- end of aside -->

<section class="first_article">
    <article>
        <p class="first_main_paragraph">Welcome to Taffies Cupcakes website! In here you will find various types of cupcakes we offer. Our cupcakes are fresh and we deliver in 24 hours. </p>
        <p class="second_main_paragraph">Check out the gallery section to see which type of cupcake you prefer. If you don't see your favorite, you can contact us and give us suggestions on what other type of cupcakes we should offer. We take feedback seriously and want to provide the best cupcakes to our customers.</p>
        <a href="orders.html"><img src="images/contact-button.png" alt="contact_button" class="contact_button"></a>
        <img src="images/cupcake.png" alt="cupcake" class="cupcake">
    </article>
</section> <!-- end of section -->

<footer>
    <p>Taffie's Cupcakes &copy; copyright 2014</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="contact.html">contact us</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="orders.html">orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">about us</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
        </ul>
</footer> <!-- end of footer -->
</div> <!-- end of container -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(".menu").click(function(){
        $(".main_nav").toggle();
    });
</script>

</body> 
</html>


*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

header,nav,section,article,aside,footer{
    display:block;
}

.container{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

body{
    background-color:#e8d4cb;
}

header img{
    padding:43px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.first_article{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}

.first_main_paragraph{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#846a5f;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

.second_main_paragraph{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
}

.first_article .contact_button{
    float:left;
    margin-top:165px;
}

.first_article .cupcake{
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:19px;
}

.sidebar{
    float:left;
    margin:30px;


}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:myriad pro;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#3d2316;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:85px;
    padding-right:29px;
    padding-top:26px;
    padding-bottom:26px;
    width:39%;  
}

nav ul li:hover a{
    color:#e8d5cc;
}

nav ul li{
    margin-bottom:3px;
    background-color: #CBAFA2;
}

nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #3D2316;
}

.company_info{
    background-color:#cbafa2;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:right;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#3d2316;
    font-family:myriad pro;
}

.about_section{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}

.about_title{
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}

.about_text{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
}

.orders_section{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}

.orders_title{
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}

.second_order{
    margin-top:50px;
}

.order_text{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#846a5f;
}

.order_numbers{
    color:#3D2316;
}

.gallery_section{
    float:left;
    width:600px;
    margin:25px;
}

.gallery_title{
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}

.contact_section{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}

.contact_title{
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}

.contact_text{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
}

footer{
    clear:both;
    font-family:arial;
    border-top:1px solid #aa8573;
    height:100px;
}

footer p{
    color:#784f3d;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
}

footer ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#784f3d;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
}

footer ul li{
float:right;
}

footer ul li a:hover{
    color:#3d2316;
}

figure{
    float:left;
    margin:25px;
}

figcaption{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
    margin-top:15px;
}

span{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#846a5f;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

mobile responsive code:

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px){

    .container{
        width:100%;
    }

    .sidebar{
        width:100%;
        margin:0;

    }

    .main_nav{
        display:none;
    }

    .company_info{
        display:none;
    }

    .first_article{
        width:90%;
        margin-top:50px;
    }

    footer p{
        display:none;
    }

    .about_section{
        width:80%;
        margin-top:50px;
        margin-bottom:100px;
    }

    .orders_section{
        width:80%;
        margin-top:50px;
        margin-bottom:100px;
    }

    .contact_section{
        width:80%;
        margin-top:50px;
        margin-bottom:100px;
    }

    .gallery_section{
        width:80%;
        margin-top:50px;
        margin-bottom:100px;
    }

    .menu:before{
        content:"Menu";
    }

    .menu{
        font-family:myriad pro;
        font-size:20px;
        color:#3d2316;
        display:inline-block;
        padding-left:85px;
        padding-right:29px;
        padding-top:26px;
        padding-bottom:26px;
        background-color: #CBAFA2;
        margin-bottom:3px;
        cursor:pointer;
        width:100%;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cancel the default action with http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

If it's not enough, hide the element on DOM ready.

Comment: Tried the first one and it did not work. Not sure what you mean with the second.